# Netbeans put data from a query into a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans

So I made a query, It's a inner join, the query is fine. But I want to put the data that is selected from the database into variables from an other class.

You see the code

```
 Spel spel = null;
 spel.setNaamSpel(spelUniekeNaam);
```

I didn't do it for all but is this the right way to do it?

```
  public void laadSpel(String spelNaam)
{
    String LAAD_SPELERS_SQL = "SELECT spel.naam, spel.aantalTeSpelenRondes, speler.naam, speler.kleur, speler.sector, speler.aantalZilverstukken, spelbord.type, spelbord.ecoWaarde, spelbord.stratWaarde, "
            + "spelbord.xcoord, spelbord.ycoord, spelbord.aantalKamelen, spelbord.kleur" +
        "From spel INNER JOIN speler ON spel.naam = speler.Spel_naam" +
                "INNER JOIN spelbord ON spel.naam = spelbord.Spel_naam" +
            "WHERE spel.naam = '" + spelNaam + "'";



    Statement statement;
    Connection connection = PersistentieController.getInstance().getConnection();


    try
    {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(LAAD_SPELERS_SQL);

        while (resultset.next())
        {
           String spelUniekeNaam = resultset.getString("spel.naam");
           String spelAantalRondes = resultset.getString("spel.aantalTeSpelenRondes");
           String spelerNaam = resultset.getString("speler.naam");
           String spelerKleur = resultset.getString("speler.kleur");
           int spelerSector = resultset.getInt("speler.sector");
           int spelerKrediet = resultset.getInt("speler.aantalZilverstukken");
           String spelbordType = resultset.getString("spelbord.type");
           int spelbordEco = resultset.getInt("spelbord.ecoWaarde");
           int spelbordStrat = resultset.getInt("spelbord.stratWaarde");
           int spelbordX = resultset.getInt("spelbord.xcoord");
           int spelbordY = resultset.getInt("spelbord.ycoord");
           int spelbordAantalKamelen = resultset.getInt(("spelbord.aantalKamelen"));
           String spelbordKleur = resultset.getString("spelbord.kleur");

           Spel spel = null;
           spel.setNaamSpel(spelUniekeNaam);


        }

         statement.close();

    } catch (SQLException e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

1. Your other class `Spel` variable will not be present outside the while loop.
2. The `spelUniekeNaam` will be overwritten with every new record traversed in the resultset.
3. Please avoid using String concatenation for SQL queries as I pointed out in your earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771066/sql-queries-in-java-jdbc-how-to-use-the-select-statement/23771133?). This is just asking for an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Oke I will change that but how can I store the selected data to spel.setNaamspel?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with it. If you require the object outside `laadSpel`, then you will have to pass this `spel` object back or take an empty `spel` as a parameter into the method.

Comment: Look into `ArrayList` which you can use to create an 'array' of objects that will hold the information from your DB table, considering you don't know how many results will be returned from the SQL query.